# How to make equal objects on ruby?

Tags: ruby, class

The challenge is to make a class that build equals objects for the same value for example:

```
class Person

att_reader :name

def initialize(name)
@name = name
end
end
```

I want to make

```
p1 = Person.new('joe')
p2 = Person.new('joe')
p3 = Person.new('mary')

p1 == p2 #true
p2 == p3 #false
```

I already tried to look for singleton but I **can't make method new to be private**

Comment: I don't understand why you believe the method must be private. To execute `p1 == p2` it must be public.

Comment: It was because the only way I found to solve this problem was using singleton like this https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/05/singleton-pattern-in-ruby/ 
. I  didn't know that was possible to change the == method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `Comparable` mixin

```
class Person
  include Comparable
  
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def <=>(other)
    name <=> other.name
  end
end
```

Comment: Why `Comparable` rather than just `def ==(other); name == other; end`?

Comment: wouldn't be `name == other.name`? anyway yes, implementing comparable gives you more methods but maybe op user don't need them